# Does boost:: or std::normal_distribution use inverse cumulative distribution function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, random, boost

The specification for my project asks to produce normally distribute random numbers, and it specifically requires that I use inverse cumulative distribution function to convert uniformly distributed numbers to the standard normal ones.

The reason for this requirement: an older "polar" method exists, where a pair of uniformly distributed random numbers is converted to a pair of normally distributed numbers, which also involves throwing away the original numbers in some cases. This older method is known to produce imperfect distribution tails.

I want to use either `std::normal_distribution` or `boost::normal_distribution`, combined with corresponding random number engine. Is there a guarantee in C++ standard that precludes using polar method?

If not, I'd like to know for sure  that either `Visual C++ 14.2` or `boost` uses the modern method (inverse cumulative normal distribution). I don't need portability.

Comment: AFAIK there are no guarantees for that. Look at some different implementation and copy one that meets your needs to your own header and use that.

Comment: Can't answer regarding C++/Boost, but [this paper](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~wl/papers/07/csur07dt.pdf) has a quite comprehensive discussion of dealing with tail issues in generating normals.

Comment: Might want to crosspost this to the boost mailing list.